# Plots are not visible using matplotlib plt.show()

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, matplotlib, plot

I'm really new in Python and Linux and I need help, I tried to use matplotlib for showing a simple plot in the following way:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot([5,6,7,8], [7,3,8,3])
plt.show()
```

But, when I run `python3 test.py`, I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py:18: UserWarning: The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo. Try installing cairocffi.
  "The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo. "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 69, in on_draw_event
    buf, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
NotImplementedError: Surface.create_for_data: Not Implemented yet.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 69, in on_draw_event
    buf, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
NotImplementedError: Surface.create_for_data: Not Implemented yet.
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:215: Warning: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._idle_event_id)
```

and an empty figure without white canvas:

[image]

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Must be a problem with the graphics modules on Linux. May need to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see:

```
"The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo."
```

And so the ***suggestion*** presented is:

```
Try installing cairocffi.
```

The [**installation guide**](https://pythonhosted.org/cairocffi/overview.html) for `cairocffi` is pretty straight-forward. If the dependencies<sup>1</sup> are met it is as simple as:

```
pip install cairocffi
```

---

<sup>1) The dependencies for `Python 3.x` ***should*** logically be:</sup>

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pip3 install cairocffi`?