# Why does my plot freeze/not show in matplotlib outside of Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, backend

So I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

plt.ion()

example_data = np.random.randint(5, size=(44,80))
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['black','white','green','blue','red'])
bounds = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

img = plt.imshow(example_data, interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.draw()
```

If I run this with the backend in matplotlibrc set to Qt4Agg, I get the plot appearing but the window is 'Not responding' and needs to be forced to close.

If I run it with the backend set to GTK3Agg (Which is what I'm aiming for really) I get a blank plot window with no plot on it and the message 'python.exe has stopped working'

If I run it within Spyder then it all works fine (Backend is Qt4Agg here I think). I get exactly what I want and no freezing/unresponsiveness.

Could anyone help? I think I'm not fully understanding the interactive issues with running it outside of the IDE.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Error log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File"<string>", line 73, in execInThread
  File"<string>", line 44, in __call__
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 196, in __call__
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncerq
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 431, in sync_request
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 379, in serve
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 337, in _recv
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\channel.py", line 50, in recv
  File"C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\stream.py", line 166, in read
EOFError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

EDIT2:

So looking in the Windows Event viewer logs I can see I get:

ERROR - APPLICATION ERROR:

```
Faulting Application name:python.exe, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x54f9ed12
Faulting module name: libcairo-2.dll, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x50a184bb
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00023024
Faulting process id: 0xca8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1f7a6ba424ee5
Faulting application path: C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\GTK+-Bundle-3.6.1\bin\libcairo-2.dll
Report Id: ff7c449c-6399-11e6-ba70-0cc47a6a54fd
```

So maybe it's something to do with the libcairo-2.dll? I reinstalled GTK to see if that helped but appears to have made no difference.

Comment: To see the plot appear, add a `plt.show()` just before your `plt.draw()` and remove the `plt.ion()`. Or w/ interactive mode on, add `plt.show(block=True)`.

Comment: This mostly works with Qt4Agg, When I use the 'block=True' method it shows me a responsive plot but when I close it, it spawns another unresponsive blank plot window which I have to force close. The removing ion() method works fine for QT4Agg. Neither work for GTK3Agg though which is what I really want, I still get the same error: 'python.exe has stopped working'.

Comment: What OS and python version are you using? You may want to check: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329921/plots-are-not-visible-using-matplotlib-plt-show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329921/plots-are-not-visible-using-matplotlib-plt-show).

Comment: Windows 7 and Python 3.4.3. I went through that earlier today and resolved by installing cairocffi as expected. I don't actually see any error messages now, just get a blank plot window and python crashes.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the stack trace?

Comment: I have added it above. Incorrect above when I said 'I don't see any error messages now' - Sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120713/discussion-between-abhishek-balaji-r-and-bloodsexmagik).

Answer (score 0):

In PyScripter 2.7.10 in menu Run-> Python engine -> Internal.